# Could you tell me about eyeshot' kernel

Tags: eyeshot

What is the kernel using in eyeshot? Is it an original kernel or parasolid?

Answer (score 0):

It's an original kernel written in C# language.
It includes some open-source libraries listed here: https://www.devdept.com/Company/Legal#eula (at chapter 5)

Comment: Link is now dead.

Comment: I just updated the link.